# Why is this code compiling while according to Rust's ownership semantics it should not?

Tags: rust

```rust
fn main() {
    let arr: [i32; 4] = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    let arr1: [i32; 4] = arr;
    println!("{:p}", &arr[0]); // return same address
    println!("{:p}", &arr1[0]); // return same address
    fn take_index(a: [i32; 4]) {
        print!("{}", a[2]);
    }
    take_index(arr1);
    print!("{}", arr[0]);
}
```

According to the ownership model of Rust, after line 3 `arr` is no longer an owner and trying to access is should be give an error. But this code compiles fine, and moreover, printing the address of both `arr[0]` and `arr1[0]` give the same value, showing multiple memory ownership for same memory.

Why is this so?

Comment: [The printing does not give the same address](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7c7329d68a4a01a3779b81b567a98e58).

Answer (score 2):

> According to the ownership model of Rust, after line 3 arr is no longer an owner and trying to access is should be give an error.

No, because [arrays are `Copy` if their content is `Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html#impl-Copy-110).

That is also why `take_index` does not invalidate `arr1`.

> printing the address of both arr[0] and arr1[0] give the same value, showing multiple memory ownership for same memory.

As Chayim Friedman commented, it does not give the same address. Nor do `&arr` and `&arr1`.

You can also see this divergence [if you update one of the arrays](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7c7329d68a4a01a3779b81b567a98e58):

```rust
fn main() {
    let arr: [i32; 4] = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    let mut arr1: [i32; 4] = arr;
    println!("{:p}", &arr[0]); // return same address
    println!("{:p}", &arr1[0]); // return same address
    println!("{:?} {:?}", arr, arr1);
    arr1[0] = 42;
    println!("{:?} {:?}", arr, arr1);
}
```

```
0x7ffcd169db18
0x7ffcd169db28
[1, 2, 3, 4] [1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4] [42, 2, 3, 4]
```